# Can’t boot from USB on Windows tablet

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb

I have a Windows tablet ZTE W105 that I want to install Linux on. The tablet finds the USB stick but when I boot from it nothing happens, it just restarts and returns to Windows. I have tried changing the priority in UEFI, using GPT instead of mar when etching the USB.

I have no idea why it doesn’t work any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check in BIOS if Secure Boot is ON.

Comment: "a windows tablet" is not very specific. Search for "Ubuntu <tablet name>". Likely you'll find step-by-step directions, or at least useful advice, in any search engine.

Comment: @John Secure Boot is disabled, should I enable it?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the tablet is a ZTE W105, I tried searching but found nothing useful. It seems as if very few people bought the tablet :/

Comment: If secure boot is disabled, USB should start.

Comment: After I select the USB the tablet restarts and returns to windows as if nothing has happened. Could there be like a lock or something to keep users from installing new OS? @John

Comment: I am not sure about that. See if you can obtain and use the manufacturer's recovery USB.